# Template specialize a method

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a method which is templated, and I want add a specialization. For a function, I would write

```
template<> T function<typename T>() { /* ... */ }
```

How do I do this for a method?

Here is a minimal failing example where I need to specialize `recv` for `<char>`.

```
#include <vector>

class recver_t {
public:

    // recv should work for chars, ints, and lists of those.

    template <typename list_t, typename elem_t>
    list_t recv() {
        list_t list;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            list.push_back(recv<elem_t>());
        }
        return list;
    }

    // How to specify this template?
    // It needs to be a template taking 1 typename, but specialized for <char>
    // I need the template spec because I am overloading by return-type.
    char recv() {return '\0';}

    // likewise, but for int
    //int recv() {return 0;}
};

int main() {
    recver_t recver;
    // std::vector<char> result = recver.recv<std::vector, char>();
    // EDIT: should be this
    std::vector<char> result = recver.recv<std::vector<char>, char>();
}
```

- I might omit the template-spec and rely on C++'s function overloading, but this won't work because I am overloading by return-type.

Comment: What's the diffrence between a method and function?

Comment: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

Comment: Clang doesn't like `template<> size_t recv<size_t>()` because `error: no function template matches function template specialization 'recv'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to make ONLY specializations, then:

First create the primary definition of the template:

```
template<typename T>
T recv();
```

Then only create the specializations:

```
template<>
char recv<char>() {return '\0';}

// likewise, but for int
template<>
int recv<int>() {return 0;}
```

If somebody uses the templates which have a missing specialization then the linker will show an error message about missing functions.

Therefore You have to delete, either specific specializations:

```
template<> 
float recv<float>() = delete;
```

or all other specializations, but then this definition has to replace the primary definition:

```
template<typename T> 
T recv() = delete;
```

Comment: Would `template<typename T> T recv() {}` allow arbitrary types (ones that do not have specialized templates) to work? Ideally it should throw a compile error if I `recv<float>()`, because I have not supported that datatype.

Comment: Depends On what You want... Why did You add `{}`?

Comment: And You can specialize for float to throw an exception.

Comment: Could I disallow that at compile-time?

Comment: How do You mean disallow?

Comment: Ideally `recv<float>()` should throw a compile-error.

Comment: @charmoniumQ yes, make the primary template deleted: `template<typename T> T recv() = delete;`

Comment: There is no such thing as throwing a compile error. At runtime You throw an exception. At compile time You can use [static_assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/static_assert)

Comment: @bolov Should be `template<> recv<float>() = delete;`

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk No, OP want's compilation to fail on all types that don't have their own specialization of `recv`. `float` was an example.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk The intention is in *"Would `template<typename T> T recv() {}` allow arbitrary types (ones that do not have specialized templates) to work?"* The following *" Ideally it should throw a compile error if I `recv<float>()`"* is an example.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect the comments.